# how to convert time of the day in UTC time?

Tags: c

i have time of the day in seconds and i have to find the utc time since 1970, is there any api which can directly convert this time to utc time,

i m using ansi c , and working on windows platform
 platform independent api will be preferred

thanx in advance.

Comment: You mean the time of day is a number of seconds from 0 to 60 * 60 * 24 - 1?  If so, how could this possibly be converted to a date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fill in a `tm struct` with the time of day you have (you'd have to convert it into seconds/minutes/hours) and the date. Then convert it with `mktime()` in `time.h`.

Comment: i have done so and find the required results but i need some standard method to do so some sort of api,,,

Comment: @moon mktime() is standard (ANSI and POSIX) so I'm not sure why you "need some standard method". I'm afraid you'll have to write it yourself, or perhaps you can find a library that does that.